# How do I remove a specific class from the child element

Tags: javascript, html

Board is the parent
I am trying to make a button that removes both red and yellow piece from the classes

```html
<div id="board">
<div id="0-0" class="tile"></div>
<div id="0-1" class="tile red-piece"></div>
<div id="0-2" class="tile yellow-piece"></div>
//etc...
</div>
```

this is my attempt, I made a button that calls this function when clicked `resetButton.addEventListener('click', resetGame)`

please tell me what to do to fix it
attempt:

```js
function resetGame(){
        board.appendChild.classList.remove('red-piece')
        board.appendChild.classList.remove('yellow-piece')   
}
```

Edit: Just wanted to mention that this is a portion of the code, I already gave them variable/queryselectors and made the necessary css, also the divs below the board div are created using a for loop in JS, this is my attempt to make a connectfour game without using tutorials for an institute project. also I do not know in particular how to use appendChild.
Thanks for all the responses

Comment: What happens when you run this? Is there an error? Does something unexpected happen?

Comment: You don't seem to define `board` or `appendChild` or  `resetButton` either.

Comment: I did define board but forgot to mention it, and appendChild was a method and now I realize it should not been used, and I created the button and its queryselector and eventlistener but did not mention because the main problem was in the function not the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Do not use `.appendChild()` that is to add elements to the DOM to which they already are.
- Target each `.tile`

  ```
  document.querySelectorAll(".tile").forEach(tile => //...
  ```
- You can use more than one parameter with `.add()` and `.remove()`

  ```
  /*...*/ tile.classList.remove("red", "gold");
  ```

```js
document.querySelector(".reset").onclick = resetBoard;

function resetBoard(event) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".tile").forEach(tile => {
    tile.classList.remove("red", "gold");
  });
}
```

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
  width: max-content;
  border: 2px ridge #ddd;
}

.tile {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px inset #ddd;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.red:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.gold {
  background-color: gold;
}

.gold:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.5);
  transition: 0.3s;
}
  
.reset {
  display: block;
  width: 270px;
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button class="reset">RESET</button>
<main>
  <div class="tile red"></div>
  <div class="tile gold"></div>
  <div class="tile red"></div>
  <div class="tile gold"></div>
  <div class="tile red"></div>
  <div class="tile gold"></div>
  <div class="tile red"></div>
  <div class="tile gold"></div>
  <div class="tile red"></div>
  <div class="tile gold"></div>
  <div class="tile red"></div>
  <div class="tile gold"></div>
  <div class="tile red"></div>
  <div class="tile gold"></div>
  <div class="tile red"></div>
  <div class="tile gold"></div>
  <div class="tile red"></div>
  <div class="tile gold"></div>
  <div class="tile red"></div>
  <div class="tile gold"></div>
  <div class="tile red"></div>
  <div class="tile gold"></div>
  <div class="tile red"></div>
  <div class="tile gold"></div>
  <div class="tile red"></div>
</main>
```

Comment: Your solution fixed my issue in particular `document.querySelectorAll(".tile").forEach(tile => {
        tile.classList.remove("red-piece", "yellow-piece");
      }); `

Comment: @HussainAlAdraj that's great, happy to help. If this answer resolved your question then you should accept it by clicking the green checkmark ✔ located to the left of this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks like you may not be fully understanding the effects of what you are writing. What do you think `appendChild()` is doing here? Where is the variable `board` being defined? The code you are trying to write may look something more like this, but I suggest you try to really understand each part of every piece of code you copy.

```
function resetGame(){
  document.querySelectorAll( '#board .tile' ).forEach( element => element.classList.remove( 'red-piece', 'yellow-piece' ) );
}
```

as for setting up the button, you need an element, and you need to use a query selector (or get by id) to get a reference to that button, so that you can add the event listener.

```
<button id="reset-button"></button>

document.getElementById( 'reset-button' ).addEventListener( 'click', resetGame );
```

Comment: To be honest I did not know what `appendChild()` does exactly in this context, I thought maybe it will grab the element that is wrapped around it which are the divs with the class tile, and then remove the additional classes by using `classlist.remove('className')`  I do have the necessary html and css and query selectors
thanks

Answer (score 1):

would this work for you?

```js
const resetButton = document.getElementById("reset-button")
resetButton.addEventListener('click', resetGame)

const board = document.getElementById("board")

function resetGame() {
  board.getElementsByClassName("red-piece")[0].classList.remove("red-piece")
  board.getElementsByClassName('yellow-piece')[0].classList.remove('yellow-piece')
}
```

```css
.red-piece {
  color: red;
}

.yellow-piece {
  color: yellow;
 }
```

```html
<div id="board">
  <div id="0-0" class="tile">tile</div>
  <div id="0-1" class="tile red-piece">tile red-piece</div>
  <div id="0-2" class="tile yellow-piece">tile yellow-piece</div>
  //etc...
</div>

<button id="reset-button">reset</button>
```

Comment: this removes the entire elements from the DOM, rather than just removing the classes from the elements. i don't think this is what they are asking for.

Comment: here, I edited it

Comment: with your new edit, it only removes the class from the first element found with those classes, and would leave the rest untouched. i believe the OP wants to remove the classes from **all** elements with those classes.